# Stripe Connect : Apple Pay is not Working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, stripe-payments, applepay

I have followed step-by-step instructions from stripe [here](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button?client=react#react-using-with-connect).

But in the end as you can see the documentation says:

```
Use the Payment Request Button with Stripe Connect by updating the stripe instance,

const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_qblFNYngBkEdjEZ16jxxoWSM', {
  apiVersion: "2023-08-16",
  stripeAccount: 'CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID',
});
```

but initially in the documentation the author has used loadStripe, but with loadStripe we cannot reinitialise the stripe instance again and connect the merchant's account.

Because underneath in my React component I am using

```
const stripe = useStripe();
```

to retrieve the stripe instance from the parent.

so can someone share an example how to connect stripe account with useStripe hook, while using loadStripe in the parent component. Basically how to update the stripe instance?

fyi, I am using in my parent component:

```
const stripe_promise = loadStripe(publishableKey, {
    stripeAccount: business.stripe_account_id,
});
```

Even the approach suggested in the comments by @karllekko, I implemented an api endpoint which creates the domain on connected account, but it is not working.

Their documentation is also wrong as you can see in the picture here, the last "s" is missing. But I have tried with adding "s" and without "s" and it is not working:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you register the domain for the connected account by calling /v1/apple_pay/domains?  https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/pmd-registration?platform=api#register-your-domain-while-using-connect  That's required for this to work.

Otherwise, your frontend code looks good. You can *not* change the instance though to change which (if any) stripeAccount is used, it can only be set on init, with loadStripe.

Comment: Yes, I have registered the domain. but the Apple pay is still not showing up.

Comment: You can see the test page here: https://www.gbpay.uk/pay/b834b7b0-91e2-4e5f-af9f-3d887f7cb77a 

although "Gpay" shows up and "Pay with Link" too. I am using a device which has apple pay activated on it and I am regularly using apple pay to make payments.

Comment: Are you sure you actually registered the domain _on the connected account_ , by passing Stripe-Account to the call to /v1/apple_pay/domains ?

Comment: Yes, I did it from the sub account dashboard. here is the screenshot that the domain was added https://ntndsbtolcxtbtmwubmj.supabase.co/storage/v1/object/public/users/0f0f909f-3074-40ea-bc28-86d27ae1efd6/1234.png

Comment: No, that is wrong and doesn't work. You must do it via the API call described at https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/pmd-registration?platform=api#register-your-domain-while-using-connect, it won't work if done through the Dashboard.

Comment: I used this code but it is not working:

const paymentMethodDomain = await stripe.paymentMethodDomains.create({
            domain_name: 'gbpay.uk',
        },{
            stripeAccount: connected_account_id,
        });

Comment: error: error
: 
"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')"

Comment: Yeah that's because you need to use the very latest version of the SDK, since that `paymentMethodDomains` API is actually new in the last week (added in https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1350---2023-09-07 ). Or on older versions, there will be an equivalent `stripe.applePayDomains.create()` function you could use to have the same effect.

Comment: I have tried using stripe.applePayDomains.create() but it is still throwing the same error : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'list')

Comment: Why "list"? There's no code for calling `.list` in what I've shared.

Comment: @Lonare were you able to solve the issue? I'm unable to see Apple Pay payment too even after creating the domain via API to the connect account, btw in a test environment it is visible.